# Executing ForEach activity against a hardcoded array in ADFv2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a set of hardcoded values for which I need to execute ForEach activity. I can create the array in the following manner and specify this as an expression in the Items setting for the ForEach activity

createArray('obj1', 'obj2','obj3')

But I get the following warning:-

Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'items'

Is there any way workaround for this so that  ForEach activity will work for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `createArray` built-in function could be implemented.

[image]

Inside ForEach Avtivity,i just configure one SetVariableActivity.

[image]

Result:

[image]